# Read XML from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xmlnode

```
SELECT 
    ref.value('tablename[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS tablename,
    ref.value('refTable[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS refTable, 
    ref.value('refTableIDColumn[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS refTableIDColumn 
FROM 
    @XMLdata.nodes('''//Table[@name="'+ @DataItem +'"]''') AS R(ref)
```

This is my code from which I am trying to fetch the node from the XML file which will satisfy the table name as `@DataItem`. I keep getting the following error

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal.

This is my XML structure

```
<Table name="abc">
    <tablename>abc1</tablename>
    <refTable>abc2</refTable>
    <refTableIDColumn>abc2ID</refTableIDColumn>
  </Table>
```

I want to fetch all nodes with `@dataItem` as abc. Please help.

Following is my correction

```
;WITH XmlData AS
(
    SELECT 
        TableNameAttribute = ref.value('@name', 'nvarchar(500)'),
        TableName = ref.value('tablename[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
        RefTable = ref.value('refTable[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'), 
        RefTableIdColumn = ref.value('refTableIDColumn[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') 
    FROM 
        @XMLdata.nodes('/Table') AS R(ref)
) 
--select * from XmlData;
INSERT INTO #TablesList 
SELECT 
    TableName, RefTable, RefTableIdColumn
FROM
    XmlData
WHERE
    XmlData.TableNameAttribute = @DataItem


select * from #TablesList;
```

After the last line I get blank table.

Comment: The error says it all: the argument for the `.nodes()` call must be a **string literal** - not a variable, not a concatenation with an argument  - just a plain, old string **literal** (a string in single quotes)

Comment: But I will have the value dynamically ony. I cannot put it statically. How to solve it

Comment: @user2998990 I am getting data with you query and the temp table is not blank...what is wrong then?

Comment: Does the **SELECT** itself (without the `INSERT INTO`) work and provide the correct answer? Then I'd say your temp table already had a blank entry or something....

Comment: If the `SELECT` alone doesn't work, then you're probably not really showing us the XML you have, and something about that XML makes the query fail...

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use string concatenations or variables in a `.nodes()` call - ***only*** string literals.

What you could do is something like this - parse the data in a CTE, and then select from that CTE based on your `@dataitem`:

```
-- create a CTE to extract the data from the XML 
;WITH XmlData AS
(
    SELECT 
        TableNameAttribute = ref.value('@name', 'nvarchar(500)'),
        TableName = ref.value('tablename[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
        RefTable = ref.value('refTable[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'), 
        RefTableIdColumn = ref.value('refTableIDColumn[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') 
    FROM 
        @XmlInput.nodes('/Table') AS R(ref)
)
-- now select from that CTE only those rows you want 
SELECT 
    TableName, RefTable, RefTableIdColumn
FROM
    XmlData
WHERE
    XmlData.TableNameAttribute = @dataitem
```

Comment: I used this and after selecting from the table which I am inserting in I get blank table.